# netbeans 8.2 javafx create exe file

Tags: javafx, netbeans, javafx-8, inno-setup

We are trying to create JavaFX 8 executable file with Netbeans 8.2 on a Windows 7 64 bit machine
We have Inno Setup installed. In the past we had no issues making executable files on a Windows 7 32 bit machine
These are the steps we used
1. Right Click the Project and Select Properties
2. Select Deployment and Check Enable Native Packaging
3. Icons & Splash Browse to Image folder (ie src/Images/S.ico) see Image folder
    you need both an S.ico and S.bmp images This is set in the Native Package Icon BOX
4. Check both Add Desktop & Add Start Menu Shortcuts
5. Run Clean and Build
6. Right Click Project then Select Package as “EXE Installer”
7. Select the Files Tab then navigate to
        -dist
        -bundles
        Which has JavaFXSlot-1.0.exe file Right Click this file
        and Select Open in System to Install the application

We have looked back at where we had Inno Setup listed in our Environment Path
In 2016 on the 64 bit it was listed as C:\Program Files\InnoSetup5;
In 2017 on the 64 bit it was changed to C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\InnoSetup5;
When we installed jdk1.8.0_144
We do not recall why or how this change happened Current ver of Inno Setup is 5.5.9(a) installed 11/2016
Here is the error we get when we try to package as EXE Installer

> Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "iscc" (in directory C:\Users\Dwight\Documents\workspace\CheckBook"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
>   C:\Users\Dwight\Documents\workspace\CheckBook\nbproject\jfx-impl.xml:3456: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\Users\Dwight\Documents\workspace\CheckBook\nbproject\jfx-impl.xml:3623: Error:
>   JavaFX native packager requires external Inno Setup 5+ tools installed and included on PATH to create EXE installer. See http://www.jrsoftware.org

We have no iss file in Inno Setup associated with the project
The project has these Libraries derby.jar and JDK 1.8 default 1.8.0_191
We are surprised by the error message as in 2016 we created an number of executable JavaFX files

**Our question is why is Netbeans 8.2 as configured not able it create a self contained exe file ?**
By self contained we would like to have the derby.jar and the JDK 1.8.jar included in the exe
We have looked at this SO question[LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42590447/netbeans-and-inno-setup-dont-produce-a-proper-native-exe)
But we are unable to follow the steps
We would rather not use Launch4j 
 
We have looked at a number of SO posted questions even older ones like Deploying JavaFX Applications at Oracle
We have included way too much information about the configuration only because we have not had an issue with this process in the past. We have not developed JavaFX applications since 2016
Our apologies if the information is not relevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are willing to bet that if you do a iscc.exe from the cmd prompt you will discover something is wrong with your Environment Path
This is because if in 2016 the process was working and nothing has changed except the addition of new JDK path being added. Plus next time post the Environment Path
Measure TWICE cut ONCE same as Copy TWICE paste ONCE ha ha

Comment: YES the Environment Path was wrong we omitted the 'm' on the end of the word Program it was PrograFiles Do the simple things FIRST

Comment: @Grendel At least the question has all the steps to make and EXE file with Netbeans 8.2 you should get 10 points for that part of the question ha ha