# Inno Setup not creating .exe from netbeans

Tags: javafx, netbeans, inno-setup

I am trying to use Inno Setup 6 to package my JavaFX programmed in Netbeans 11 file into an executable.] I've followed:
https://erainnovator.com/convert-jar-to-exe-file/ and
https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/native_pkg.html

Although [NetBeans and Inno Setup don't produce a proper Native .exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42590447/netbeans-and-inno-setup-dont-produce-a-proper-native-exe) says it could take time, there is no evidence from anywhere that Inno Setup is actually doing anything.

Should there be a separate Log that tells me if there was an error or a service running I can see in task manager or something? How long is a Long time to generate code?

Please Help.

Comment: I also generate a .exe with Innosetup for my Netbeans java app. Innosetup takes maybe 1-2min to generate the exe (~40MB, signed). In my case InnoSetup is run from a bash script called by the Netbeans Ant build script, so I see progress in the log output.

Comment: I Can't see anything on any output - it looks like its gone ok but here's no bundle file.